# Trouble using pseudo selector with a directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a directive for a table with collapsible rows that only allows one row to be open at a time like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="my-table">
    <div class="table-header">
        ... table headers ...
    </div>
    <my-table-row ng-repeat="itm in itms" itm="itm"></my-table-row>
</div>
```

JS Directive:

```
app.directive('myTable', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 
        itms: '='
    },
    controller: 'TableController',
    templateUrl: '/views/directives/my-table.html'
};
});
```

JS Controller:

```
app.controller('TableController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.rows = [];

$scope.toggleRow = function(row) {
    row.open = !row.open;
};

this.addRow = function addRow(row) {
    $scope.rows.push(row);
};

this.toggleOpen = function toggleOpen(selectedRow) {
    angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(row) {
        if (row === selectedRow) {
            $scope.toggleRow(selectedRow);
        } else {
            row.open = false;
        }
    });
};
}]);
```

and the rows like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="table-row" ng-class="{ 'open': open }" ng-click="toggleOpen(this)">
    ... row contents code ...
</div>
```

JS Directive:

```
app.directive('myTableRow', function() {
return {
    require: '^myTable',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 
        itm: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tableCtrl) {
        scope.open = false;
        scope.toggleOpen = tableCtrl.toggleOpen;
        tableCtrl.addRow(scope);
    },
    templateUrl: '/views/directives/my-table-row.html'
};
});
```

used in template like this:

```
<my-table itms="itms"></my-table>
```

This all works, but I have a CSS pseudo element to round the corners of the final row like:

```
.table .table-row:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

However, ng-repeat is wrapping a tag around my table rows which is causing the pseudo selector to see them all as the last child.  I've tried restructuring, tried using $last and making an actual class for the last row, moving things around, but I'm out of ideas.  Any thoughts out there?

Comment: Any chance you could make a plunker or jsfiddle so we can play around with it and figure it out?

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: Add `replace: true` to your 'myTableRow' directive [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `replace: true`.  Good one, @ThomasGhesquiere.  That should fix it.

Comment: Nailed it! make that an answer @ThomasGhesquiere and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understood, css class *table-row* is located within *myTableRow* directive, which does not have `replace: true` property. This means that *table-row* css class is wrapped by *my-table-row* directive attribute, so, in order to get to the last row, your CSS rule should be:

```
.table my-table-row:last-child .table-row {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

Comment: Also works. I'll accept this answer since it doesn't use the deprecated replace parameter and since the other guy didn't give his response as an answer.